# DFT calculation for conjugated polymers

Tags: density-functional-theory, electronic-structure, geometry-optimization, basis-sets, polymers

I am new to DFT calculation.
I want to know the structure of conjugated polymers (*plane angle, etc.*) and their electronic and optical properties (*such as HOMO-LUMO, IR, etc.*).

I am using **6-311+G(d)** for heavy atoms and **6-31G** for hydrogen with **B3LYP**. My question is that setup ok for supporting my experimental data? Or I have to use different method and basis set?

Comment: It's okay, but I wouldn't suggest those old basis sets, and I'd definitely recommend using dispersion corrections. What program are you using? There are better newer functionals, but B3LYP isn't bad for a start at modeling conjugated polymers particularly if you want to compare optical gaps.

Comment: I am using Gaussian 09 D.01 now, I could also use Orca at some point but not so good. Are there any good functionals that don't require too much computational power? (I've use cc-pVTZ but it cost too much time). Thank you for your answers

Answer (score 6):

Apologies I do not have enough reputation points to post this as a comment. You might have already considered other electronic structure methods, but I would like to suggest consider using density matrix renormalisation group (DMRG) based methods for the calculations. DMRG is highly suitable for modelling conjugated polymers. For example, [here](https://pubs.aip.org/aip/jcp/article/128/14/144117/847909/Orbital-optimization-in-the-density-matrix) is an example of DMRG-CASSCF calculations on linear polyenes, and [here](https://pubs.aip.org/aip/jcp/article/127/13/134309/567089/The-radical-character-of-the-acenes-A-density) is an example of calculations on acenes.

DMRG methods are supported by several open source quantum chemistry packages, and I found [psi4](https://psicode.org), which utilises [CheMPS2](https://github.com/SebWouters/CheMPS2) particularly easy to use.

Edit :

As pointed out by @wzkchem5, DMRG does not take into account dynamical correlations. For NEVPT2/DMRG calculations on polyene systems, please see [this](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/acs.jpcb.9b04027) and [this](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/acs.jpca.0c01678).

Comment: A small comment: for quantitative accuracy, dynamic correlation has to be modeled as well on top of the DMRG wavefunction, for example by NEVPT2.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. Please see [this paper](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/acs.jpcb.9b04027) for an example of DMRG with NEVPT2.